# CSS to center align the text input, text areas and select option

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to use text align center in my CSS to align my form to no avail. I have ommitted the CSS from this code below. The font style also looks different between what I want and what I have. I also don't know how to change the font style in CSS. Here is my html form:

```
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en">
                <head>
                <title>Add/Edit Supplier</title>
                <style>
                </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                <strong>Add/Edit Supplier</strong><hr>

                <?php
                echo form_open('supplier/save', array('name' => 'supplier_add'));    
                ?>

                <label>Supplier</label>
                <input type="text" name="supplier" id="supplier"> <br/>

                <label>PIN</label>
                <input type="text" name="taxpin" id="taxpin"> <br/>

                <label>Contact</label>
                <input type="text" name="contact" id="contact"> <br/>

                <label>Address</label>
                <textarea  name="addresss" id="addresss"></textarea> <br/>

                <label>City</label>
                <select name="citys" id="citys">>
                <option value="">All</option>
                <?php

                foreach($cities as $city)
                {
                echo '<option value="'.$city['cityidd'].'">'.$city['city'].'</option>';
                }
                ?>  
                </select> <br/>


                <label>Telephone</label>
                <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone"> <br/>

                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email"> <br/>

                <label>Website</label>
                <input type="text" name="website" id="website"> <br/>

                <label>Payment Mode</label>
                <select name="paymentmodes" id="paymentmodes">>
                <option value="">--Please select--</option>
                <?php
                foreach($modes as $mode)
                {
                echo "<option value='".$mode['id']."'>".$mode['paymentmode']."</option>";
                }
                ?>  
                </select> <br/>

                <label>KES Account</label>
                <input type="number" name="kesaccount" id="kesaccount"> <br/>

                <label>USD Account</label>
                <input type="number" name="usdaccount" id="usdaccount"> <br/>

                <label>Bank</label>
                <select name="banks" id="banks">
                <option value="">--Please select--</option>
                <?php
                foreach($banks as $bank)
                {
                echo '<option value="'.$bank['id'].'">'.$bank['bankname'].'</option>';

                }
                ?>  
                </select> <br/>

                <label>Bank Branch</label>
                <select name="bankbranches" id="bankbranches">
                <option value=""></option>
                </select> <br/>

                <script type= text/javascript>
                $('#banks').on('change', function() {
                var bank = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'supplier/get_branches',
                data: { bank_id : bank },
                success: function (response) {
                $('#bankbranches').html(response); 
                }
                });
                });
                </script>

                <label>Bank Branch Code</label>
                <input type="number" name="bankcode" id="bankcode"> <br/>

                <label>SWIFT</label>
                <input type="text" name="swiftcode" id="swiftcode"> <br/>

                <label>Mobile Payment Number</label>
                <input type="number" name="mobilepaymentnumber" id="mobilepaymentnumber"> <br/>

                <label>Mobile Payment Name</label>
                <input type="number" name="mobilepaymentname" id="mobilepaymentname"> <br/>

                <label>Cheque Addressee</label>
                <input type="number" name="chequeddressee" id="chequeaddressee"> <br/>

                <label>Status</label>
                <input type="radio" name="status" value="1" checked="checked">Yes
                <input type="radio" name="status" value="0">No <br/>

                <label>Category</label>
                <select name="categorysuppliers" id="categorysuppliers">
                <option value="">--Please select--</option>
                <?php
                foreach($categories as $category)
                {
                echo '<option value="'.$category['id'].'">'.$category['supplycategory'].'</option>';
                }
                ?>  
                </select> <br/>

                <label>Staff</label>
                <select name="staff" id="staff">>
                <option value="">--Non Staff--</option>
                <?php

                foreach($staffs as $staff)
                {
                echo '<option value="">'.$staff['firstname'].' '.$staff['lastname'].'</option>';
                }
                ?>  
                </select> <br/>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save Details" class="btn">
                <?php
                echo form_close();
                ?>
                </form>
                </body>
                </html>
```

Here is how it looks like in the web browser:

[image: How my html form looks in the browser]

This is how I want my html form to look like:

[image]

I don't know how to achieve this except for using text align center and so far has not brought my html form anything close to what I want.

Comment: Post your CSS as well

Comment: That is **not** center-aligned. Your second image basically has inline-block labels all set to the same width.

Comment: what happens if you add this to your CSS: `label{width: 250px;}`  - or whatever width you want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Addressing nothing else in your question, this is a simple example with a small part of your form:

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<label>Supplier</label>
<input type="text" name="supplier" id="supplier">
<br/>

<label>PIN</label>
<input type="text" name="taxpin" id="taxpin">
<br/>

<label>Contact</label>
<input type="text" name="contact" id="contact">
<br/>
```

With a button lined up beneath the inputs:

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}

button{
    margin-left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<label>Supplier</label>
<input type="text" name="supplier" id="supplier">
<br/>

<label>PIN</label>
<input type="text" name="taxpin" id="taxpin">
<br/>

<label>Contact</label>
<input type="text" name="contact" id="contact">
<br/>
<br />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: wow! Thanks, it really worked. I tried to do the same with the submit button by doing this:      `label, submit {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 25%;
     }` But the submit button remains left aligned.

Comment: Okay, what were you expecting to happen? That rule only sets the width of the matching elements. If you want a element to be pushed to the left the same amount, you need to set a `margin-left`.

Comment: I never knew that the rule only sets the width of the matching elements. Nevertheless, thanks. I am better than I was a few hours ago

Comment: I don't particularly see how a "width" rule could be construed as anything but setting an element's width. If you're new to CSS, I would recommend reading a decent resource before you go much further. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS), for instance, has a generally good resource for CSS

Comment: I will sure visit the site to get insights on CSS

Answer (score 0):

Start with 200px and increase that until it's centered enough for your needs.

```
label { width:200px; display: inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

the [style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/758dS.png) tag inside your code is also not closed, it might be create some problem

Comment: please refer to the above fiddle link , Note :  you will have to add your php code wherever needed.

Comment: just copy pasting the code inside the fiddle shall solve the problem

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I did correct that error by enclosing the tag